# Control HTTP headers from outer Go middleware

Tags: http, go, middleware

Let's say I have a middleware in Go where I want to override any existing `Server` headers with my own value.

```
// Server attaches a Server header to the response.
func Server(h http.Handler, serverName string) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Server", serverName)
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

Then I add it to a response chain like this

```
http.Handle("/", authHandler)
http.ListenAndServe(":8000", Server(http.DefaultServeMux, "myapp"))
```

Unfortunately, if the authHandler or anything handled by DefaultServeMux calls `w.Header().Add("Server", "foo")` (like, say, [httputil.ReverseProxy.ServeHTTP](https://golang.org/src/net/http/httputil/reverseproxy.go?s=3769:3844#L221)), I end up with two Server headers in the response.

```
$ http localhost:5962/v1/hello_world
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 11
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Tue, 12 Jul 2016 04:54:04 GMT
Server: inner-middleware
Server: myapp
```

What I really want is something like this:

```
// Server attaches a Server header to the response.
func Server(h http.Handler, serverName string) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        w.Header().Set("Server", serverName)
    })
}
```

However, this is [disallowed by the semantics of ServeHTTP](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler):

> ServeHTTP should write reply headers and data to the ResponseWriter and then return. Returning signals that the request is finished; it is not valid to use the ResponseWriter or read from the Request.Body after or concurrently with the completion of the ServeHTTP call.

I have seen some fairly ugly hacks around this, for example the code in [httputil.ReverseProxy.ServeHTTP](https://golang.org/src/net/http/httputil/reverseproxy.go?s=3769:3844#L221), which copies headers and rewrites the response code, or using httptest.ResponseRecorder, which reads the entire body into a byte buffer.

I could also reverse the traditional middleware order and put my Server middleware last, somehow, or make it the inner-most middleware.

Is there any simple method I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a custom type which wraps a ResponseWriter and inserts the Server header just before all headers are written, at the cost of an additional layer of indirection. Here is an example:

```
type serverWriter struct {
    w           http.ResponseWriter
    name        string
    wroteHeader bool
}

func (s serverWriter) WriteHeader(code int) {
    if s.wroteHeader == false {
        s.w.Header().Set("Server", s.name)
        s.wroteHeader = true
    }
    s.w.WriteHeader(code)
}

func (s serverWriter) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    return s.w.Write(b)
}

func (s serverWriter) Header() http.Header {
    return s.w.Header()
}

// Server attaches a Server header to the response.
func Server(h http.Handler, serverName string) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        sw := serverWriter{
            w:           w,
            name:        serverName,
            wroteHeader: false,
        }
        h.ServeHTTP(sw, r)
    })
}
```

I wrote more about this here. https://kev.inburke.com/kevin/how-to-write-go-middleware/

Comment: This is a perfect example of overengineering it. Really all that you need to do is change the place of where the header gets written and write it before calling WriteHeader().

Comment: I'm really confused by your comment. It's impossible to override an internal middleware from an outer middleware. In this case I'm calling httputil.ReverseProxy.ServeHTTP to proxy to code I don't control. ReverseProxy.ServeHTTP calls WriteHeader on whatever the proxy returns; I can't control that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change headers (add/remove/modify) after you use WriteHeader(Status).

For this to work, change to:

```
// Server attaches a Server header to the response.
func Server(h http.Handler, serverName string) http.Handler {
  return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Server", serverName)
    h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
  })
}
```

Comment: sorry - I don't see how that differs from my first code snippet?

Comment: The position of write header vs h.ServeHTTP, diff the code.

Comment: Ah - I have two code snippets in my question, the first matches what you have written, the second is an example of what I want to do, and I note that it's incorrect.

Comment: How does this answer the question? You just repeated the code in the Question.